# Cant connect to Linux VM on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a new Ubuntu VM running Docker on Azure . I have used password as the means of Authentication method . I have received the message that VM has been created is is running . However the Connect button is disabled and only Restart and Stop are enabled . Im not sure how to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) is a proprietary protocol used for Windows. How can we use RDP to connect to a Linux VM (virtual machine) remotely? so you can not connect Linux VM in remotely

You'll need to install an SSH client on the computer you want to use to log on to the virtual machine. There are many SSH client programs that you can choose from.
please follow below link:- 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-log-on/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-remote-desktop/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/682948/Remote-desktop-connection-to-Ubuntu-VM-in-the-Azur

Comment: This is not entirely accurate, as you *can* install RDP on Linux VMs.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ?

Comment: Nothing more to elaborate on: You can install an RDP server on a Linux VM. Easy to do, and easy to do a google search. There's even an [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-remote-desktop/) on the Azure site itself describing how to do it.

Comment: Thanks David your comment was helpful.